# Getting access to ArrayList object

Tags: c#, json, object, dictionary

I'm developing an application that reads some JSON data and makes some statistics, but now I've run into a problem.

I have a string like this:

```
{
"position":[
  {
     "someKey1":"someVal1",
     "someKey2":"someVal2",
  },
  {
     "someKey1":"someVal3",
     "someKey2":"someVal4",
  }
}
```

I want to access the someKeys and someValues.

I'm converting it to a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = deserializeJSON(json_string);
```

**Edit 1:** Sorry, forgot to add deserializeJSON:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> deserializeJSON(string p_jsonObject)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(p_jsonObject);
}
```

Now I have trouble getting access to the list of values with the key "position". If I try to print the type of values["position"] I get:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

So I thought I could just iterate through this, but I can't. I tried using enumerator (read in here that it would make it possible to iterate over the objects, and that I have to add it to an ArrayList to cast it):

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
IEnumerable enumerable = values["position"] as IEnumerable;

foreach (object element in enumerable)
{
    arr.Add(element);
}
```

When I print arr[0] I get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

Here I'm confused. I assume it's the list of someKeys and someVals, which should be correct, right?
Now I've tried, with no luck, getting access to these values. I tried arr[0]["someKey1"] but get an error that I cannot apply indexing to 'object'.

Any ideas on a solution? Ideally a more elegant solution? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your string suggests an array of dictionary value lists.  I think you'll need to change that.

Comment: > I tried arr[0]["someKey1"] Have you tried modifying that to something like `((Dictionary<Object>)arr[0]).["someKey1"]`?

Comment: You have missing square bracket for array definition

Comment: How are you expecting to use the dictionary "values"? What does your "deserializeJSON" do? Can you post that code and also, can you correct your JSON, so there is no room for assumptions about it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Updated now :)
What do you mean by correcting my JSON? That's how my input looks.

Comment: It requires 2 type arguments. Tried with <string, string>. It now returns the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Linq to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) (add Newtonsoft's JSON.NET from NuGet):

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var value = (string)jo["position"][1]["someKey1"]; // someVal3
```

Another sample:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray positions = (JArray)jo["position"];
foreach (var item in positions)
{
    // use (string)item["someKey1"]
    // use (string)item["someKey2"]
}
```

Comment: Wow, amazing that it could be done so simple with Linq to JSON. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the elements as follows:

[image: LinqPad Demo]

```
var enumerable = (IEnumerable)values["position"]; // Will get you the enumerable ArrayList
(Dictionary<string,object>)values["position"][0]; // Will get you the First element of the ArrayList
(string)values["position"][0]["someKey1"]; // Will get you someKey1 from the first position of position
```

Comment: Lovely! And without external modules. Might become quite handy :)